# How do I get a popup menu to block clicks from hitting UI elements beneath it?

Tags: unity, events

You can see in the picture that I have a Canvas with a popup menu in it. I just enable this, and it covers the main menu stuff. Clicks go through it and hit stuff in the main menu.

[image]

I've tried adding an EventTrigger to the PopupRoot object, and adding an event to listen for PointerClick events, but it doesn't fire.

```
EventTrigger trigger = m_popUpRoot.GetComponentInChildren<EventTrigger>();
EventTrigger.Entry entry = new EventTrigger.Entry();
entry.eventID = EventTriggerType.PointerClick;
entry.callback.AddListener((eventData) => { PopupClickBlocker((PointerEventData)eventData); });
trigger.triggers.Add(entry);
```

I'm open to other suggestions. My current system is horrible; button click events query the Popup to see if it's enabled or not, then return doing nothing if it is. This doesn't work for sliders very well, so I want to do this the right way.

Comment: I guess every Unity canvas has its own input. One solution would be to put elements in 1 canvas and set raycast target. Btw why do you need multiple canvases if they are the same type, overlay? I think it's slower than 1 canvas with many elements. Try changing canvas order, this may help.

Comment: "Slower" by how much? I'm sure the speed difference is not noticable. I'm not much for micro-optimizations.

Comment: I have tried with 50 canvases, it was pretty slow, but yeah 3 and 50 is much of a difference.

Comment: How "slow"? I want data from the profiler telling me how many milliseconds are lost per frame. Just "it was pretty slow" means nothing to me.

Comment: Hey, it was a long time ago, I don't have access to a project anymore. And it's just a comment, but you are behaving like someone owns you anything. Just gave you an advice, pretty slow - means game is slow and I think it was intuitive that its somewhere between 30-45 fps drop, while game is running on 100 fps, that is all I remember.

Comment: Why do you use a SpriteRenderer instead of the Image component ?

Comment: @CandidMoon I was told to use for(int i = 0, int count = list.count; i < count; i++) because List.count is "slow". I profiled it: lost 0.5 sec on 500,000,000 calls. Not worth worrying about. Many, many programmers get caught up in micro-optimization, so I treat any claim of "slow" with skepticism. 2 Canvases rather than 1 is for sure not relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a `GraphicRaycaster` object on the root popup `Canvas` object, and set it to "Blocking Mask = Everything".

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use a [CanvasGroup](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-CanvasGroup.html) on the PopupRoot, and check the "Block Raycasts" option.

This will make the element block raycast from the elements behind it.

Comment: Didn't work. :(

Comment: ouch, my bad! I've just realized that you use separate canvases for the Menu and Popup elements.

Then you should do the opposite: have a CanvasGroup somewhere under MenuCanvas that has the Block Raycasts option UNchecked.

Comment: Ok! Will try that tonight.

Comment: When I do as Raziel suggests then my main canvas is no longer clickable. It appears Unity forgot to add some essentials like a proper UI mask.